# How to submit html with array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to post html form (with array data) with just javascript?

Hi guys,

I have a simple HTML where user can select multiple rows from a html table. I have a button where it will submit a form to the backend. I've tested with single entry(before i made changes to array).

I've tried researching and here is where I'm at now. I tried to submit the form but i believe the values are not passed correctly.

If anyone could review my code and guide me, that would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<form id="frmbasket" name="frmbasket" action="SAPEVENT:POST" method="post" target="_top">
    <div class="container"> 
    <table id=table class="scroll">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>MaterialType</th>
                <th>MaterialGroup</th>
                <th>MaterialDesc</th>
                <th>Plant</th>
                <th>Storage Location</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Item Category</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            </tr>       
        </tbody>
        </table>
            <input type="hidden" id="fDesc" name="aItems[NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION]"> 
            <input type="hidden" id="fMat" name="aItems[NEW_ITEM-MATNR"> 
            <input type="hidden" id="fMgroup" name="aItems[NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP]"> 
            <input type="hidden" id="fQty" name="aItems[NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY]"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-UNIT[1]" value = "EA"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="aItems[NEW_ITEM-PRICE]">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-PRICEUNIT[1]" value = "5"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CURRENCY[1]" value = "USD">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LEADTIME[1]" value = "1"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDOR[1]" value = ""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDORMAT[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MANUFACTCODE[1]" value = ""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MANUFACTMAT[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT_ITEM[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-SERVICE[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_QUOTE_ID[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_QUOTE_ITEM[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_PRODUCT_ID[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_1:132[1]" value = "longtext_1: Test Text">
            <input type="hidden" id="fCustField1" name="aItems[NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1]">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD2[1]" value = "custf 1.2">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD3[1]" value = "custf 1.3">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD4[1]" value = "custf 1.4">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD5[1]" value = "custf 1.5">
    </div>
  </form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        document.frmbasket.submit();
    });
});
```

the array is aItems

```
aItems
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {KeyIndex: 1, NEW_ITEM-MATNR: "5", NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP: "31260000", NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION: "Casings", NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1: "N", …}
1: {KeyIndex: 3, NEW_ITEM-MATNR: "1511", NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP: "31260000", NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION: "Casings", NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1: "N", …}
2: {KeyIndex: 5, NEW_ITEM-MATNR: "1513", NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP: "31260000", NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION: "Casings", NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1: "N", …}
3: {KeyIndex: 7, NEW_ITEM-MATNR: "1514", NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP: "31260000", NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION: "Casings - No MMSL", NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1: "N", …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I'm not using PHP so I was wondering if I can still submit form with multiple entries in an array? I dont have experiences with PHP, thats why I'm just trying with javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: You have SAPEVENT:POST  . what is the issue with PHP?

Comment: Before this I was able to submit single entries. but now I have have an array that needs to be submitted. Is there a way to do this via javascript? this form will be sent back to SAP ECC for processing. Single entry works but I'm trying to submit an array(multiple selection from table)

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. If the form works, the submit will submit what is in the form. If you have an array.. serialize it

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to ask correctly as well . The last time I posted it like this  `<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[1]"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATNR[1]"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP[1]" > 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY[1]" >` instead of doing hardcoded increments like `NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[2], NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[3], NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[4]` am I able to post it according to the number of objects in the array?

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it.

All I had to do was loop through my array and create the form dynamically and posting it after that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        alert("Submitted");

        // var $form = $('<form />', { action: 'SAPEVENT:POST', method: 'post' });
         //Create form
         aItems.unshift("Blank"); //OCI starts with parameter[1] so if we loop through array, array[0] won't be picked
         var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
         $(form).attr("action", "SAPEVENT:POST");
         $(form).attr("method", "post");
         for (var index = 0; index < aItems.length; ++index) {
                var MatDesc = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", 'NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION' + '[' + index + ']').val(aItems[index]["NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION"]);
                var MatNo = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", 'NEW_ITEM-MATNR' + '[' + index + ']').val(aItems[index]["NEW_ITEM-MATNR"]);
                var MatGrp = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", 'NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP' + '[' + index + ']').val(aItems[index]["NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP"]);
                var CustField1 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", 'NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1' + '[' + index + ']').val(aItems[index]["NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1"]);
                var Price = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", 'NEW_ITEM-PRICE' + '[' + index + ']').val(aItems[index]["NEW_ITEM-PRICE"]);
                var Qty = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", 'NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY' + '[' + index + ']').val(aItems[index]["NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY"]);
         $(form).append($(MatDesc));
         $(form).append($(MatNo));
         $(form).append($(MatGrp));
         $(form).append($(CustField1));
         $(form).append($(Price));
         $(form).append($(Qty));
         };
         form.appendTo( document.body )
         $(form).submit();       
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your docready function might not actually be submitting the form. Try changing it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#frmbasket').submit();
    });
});
```

because I think that document.frmbasket is undefined.

Comment: Hey Dov, my apologies...I removed an extra line when creating my post earlier. I've updated my post lol